# Remove inherited middleware in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have the following scenario:

```
class BaseApp < Sinatra::Base
  use Custom::Middleware
end

class MyApp < BaseApp
end
```

Is there a way to unload Custom::Middleware on MyApp? I have searched for a method that does the opposite of **use** but haven't found anything. I know that it's desirable to no inherit from BaseApp but this app has a regular code base and I need a bunch of functionality from BaseApp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in Sinatra or rack (builder) that will allow you to unload middleware. Sinatra stores the middleware as an array in the @middleware instance variable.

You could try loading the custom middleware in the config.ru instead:

```
map("/myapp") { run MyApp }
map("/baseapp") do
  BaseApp.use Custom::Middleware
  run BaseApp
end
```

If that doesn't work, then remove the middleware from the BaseApp, and make another class that inherits from the BaseApp, define the custom middleware there, then MyApp will not have that middleware set.

```
class BaseApp < Sinatra::Base
end

class SomeApp < BaseApp
  use Custom::Middleware
end

class MyApp < BaseApp
end
```